# Red5 video chat tutorial AS3

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, red5, video-conferencing

Where can I find working examples of a video chat application based on AS3 and Red5?
I'm having trouble to understand how to attach a user stream to another user and vice-versa. Can someone point to a simple example or provider some sample code?

Comment: Amazing : https://www.google.com/search?q=red5+video+example

Comment: Amazing! Now try to add "AS3" and "real working sample" to the query.... ;)

Comment: Did you find anything yet @Rui?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a SimpleChat demo project from Red5: http://www.red5.org/downloads/simpledemos/

Anyway just to give you a basic concept: 
Assuming that you have a chat application, you will have a single ID for each user, right? So lets suppose a scenario where user *A* start streaming the mic/cam to user *B*:

```
//start streaming the mic and camera
nsPub = new NetStream ( netConnection );
nsPub.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
nsPub.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
nsPub.publish('A');

//need to send a command to user B to notify him that user A started streaming, 
//this command can be sent by a SharedObject or invoking a remote method, that will 
//invoke a client method in B

//code to receive the mic/cam streaming from user A
nsCli = new NetStream ( netConnection );
videoCompoment.attachNetStream( nsCli );
nsCli.play('A');
```